# Looking for iOS virtual environment to run on Windows 10

Tags: ios, ipad

We are a team working from home and can't share iPad in the office due to pandemic.. We are looking for a virtual environment of iOS (iPad) to run on Windows 10 when it's time to troubleshoot iOS related questions. I am not sure this even exists for copyright and so on but I thought asking here might get me somewhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately a legal iOS virtual environment on Windows 10 does not exist. Apple forbids, via their End User Licence Agreements (EULAs), running Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware.

The only legal iOS simulator available is included with Xcode and Xcode requires macOS.